# Is there a way in vb.net to make process start closing my program?

Tags: vb.net, process

My program checks if there is a new version of itself. If yes it would exit and start an updater that replaces it and then restarts. 
My problem is that I haven't found any info on how to make process start right after closing the actual program.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why after? Could you start the updater and then exit your program?

Answer (score 0):

I intended to add a comment, but I'm too low in points here. The updater itself should probably contain a check to determine whether your application is running an instance, and it should contain a timeout loop that performs this check and factor the timeout following it's startup state. That way you can awaken it, and close your application. The updater should just determine your application is not running, compare versions perform the intended update operation.

a possible solution would also be to create a task via tash sceduler or cron job, starting an out of process application, like CMD.exe.. which brings me to my original comment-question: in regards to what Operating System(s) and Platform(s) is your program intended for?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is for win xp and higher, written in vb.net 2010.